# uniq sort parsing

Tags: shell, sorting, awk, uniq

I have one file with field separated by ";", like this:

```
test;group;10.10.10.10;action2
test2;group;10.10.13.11;action1
test3;group3;10.10.10.10;action3
tes4;group;10.10.10.10;action4
test5;group2;10.10.10.12;action5
test6;group4;10.10.13.11;action8
```

I would like to identify all non-unique IP addresses (3rd column). With the example the extract should be:

```
test;group;10.10.10.10;action2
test3;group3;10.10.10.10;action3
tes4;group;10.10.10.10;action4
test2;group;10.10.13.11;action1
test6;group4;10.10.13.11;action8
```

Sorted by IP address (3rd column).

Ssing simple commands like `cat`, `uniq`, `sort`, `awk` (not Perl, not Python, only shell).

Any idea?

Comment: If you're using cat, uniq, sort, awk, you're not using "only shell". Perl and Python are equivalent to Awk from the shell's perspective.

Comment: except that awk is standard on every UNIX installation while perl and python aren't. awk is more like sed and grep wrt availability than it is perl or python,.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk -F';' 'NR==FNR{a[$3]++;next}a[$3]>1' file file|sort -t";" -k3
test;group;10.10.10.10;action2
test3;group3;10.10.10.10;action3
tes4;group;10.10.10.10;action4
test2;group;10.10.13.11;action1
test6;group4;10.10.13.11;action8
```

- awk picks all duplicated ($3) lines
- sort sorts by ip

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this solution using `grep`, `cut`, `sort`, `uniq`, and a casual process substitution in the middle.

```
grep -f <(cut -d ';' -f3 file | sort | uniq -d) file | sort -t ';' -k3
```

It is not really elegant (I actually prefer the `awk` answer given above), but I think worth sharing, since it accomplishes what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to Kent's answer, but with a single pass through the file. The tradeoff is memory: you need to store the lines to keep. This uses GNU awk for the PROCINFO variable.

```
awk -F';' '
    {count[$3]++; lines[$3] = lines[$3] $0 ORS} 
    END {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
        for (key in count) 
            if (count[key] > 1) 
                printf "%s", lines[key]
    }
' file
```

The equivalent perl

```
perl -F';' -lane '
    $count{$F[2]}++; push @{$lines{$F[2]}}, $_
  } END {
    print join $/, @{$lines{$_}}
        for sort grep {$count{$_} > 1} keys %count
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

here is another `awk` assisted pipeline

```
$ awk -F';' '{print $0 "\t" $3}' file | sort -sk2 | uniq -Df1 | cut -f1

test;group;10.10.10.10;action2
test3;group3;10.10.10.10;action3
tes4;group;10.10.10.10;action4
test2;group;10.10.13.11;action1
test6;group4;10.10.13.11;action8
```

single pass, so special caching; also keeps the original order (stable sorting).  Assumes tab doesn't appear in the fields.

Answer (score 0):

**`awk` + `sort` + `uniq` + `cut`:**

```
$ awk -F ';' '{print $0,$3}' <file> | sort -k2 | uniq -D -f1 | cut -d' ' -f1
```

**`sort` + `awk`**

```
$ sort -t';' -k3,3 | awk -F ';' '($3==k){c++;b=b"\n"$0}($3!=k){if (c>1) print b;c=1;k=$3;b=$0}END{if(c>1)print b}
```

**`awk`**

```
$ awk -F ';' '{b[$3"_"++k[$3]]=$0; }
      END{for (i in k) if(k[i]>1) for(j=1;j<=k[i];j++) print b[i"_"j] } <file>
```

This buffers the full file (same as `sort` does) and keeps track how many times a key `k` is appearing. At the end, if the key appears more then ones, print the full set.

```
test2;group;10.10.13.11;action1
test6;group4;10.10.13.11;action8
test;group;10.10.10.10;action2
test3;group3;10.10.10.10;action3
tes4;group;10.10.10.10;action4
```

If you want it sorted :

```
$ awk -F ';' '{b[$3"_"++k[$3]]=$0; }
      END{ asorti(k,l); 
      for (i in l) if(k[l[i]]>1) for(j=1;j<=k[l[i]];j++) print b[l[i]"_"j] } <file>
```